# Basement Wiring

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

I live in a home built in 2018.  The basement is unfinished and there are 4 lights fixtures (socket) on a three way switch.  I can turn the lights on at the stairwell and the other at the exit door.  I want to replace on the the porcelain light fixtures and cannot seem to get correct.  On the one I am replacing there are two white (one hot and one not), a green ground wire, and a red wire exposed that were connected to the fixture.  There are two black (capped together). If I check for voltage there is one white and the red that both have power at all times unless I throw the main breaker (both are hot with switch on or off).  In the other two light fixture I have two red wires and two white wires connected to the fixture and two black wire (capped off together). I believe the red and white wires are al hot in these two fixtures. I have not removed the 4 light fixture. on the light fixture I am working on I have tried using one white (neutral) and one red.  But the lights are dim.  Not enough power.  I tried to use a hot white and the red with no success.  ( In both scenario I capped of the 3rd wire).  This seems to control the power outlets as well as there is no power at the outlets.  This is all on a GFCI breaker also on the basement.

Comment: Just remove the porcelain fixtures and hook up your new fixtures to the same wires the same way they were connected to the old ones. You've got a three way switch setup which has more wires and not necessarily the color you'd expect. Don't try to figure out what's going on until you study up on three way switch wiring.

Comment: Don't try to get creative with the wiring. It was wired the way it was for a reason, and presumably it worked that way. Leave well-enough alone - simply replace the old fixture with your new one with exactly the same wiring.

Comment: Which wires were previously connected to the light fixture?  Are you messing with other wires? *don't, they're not 'spares' they have a job*.

Comment: Agree with Jack some wires are travelers and they will change who is hot depending on switch positions connect the new fixtures to the same wires as the old.